# Routes setting when press the button generated by link_to tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, routes

When I click the link below, it goes to `/messages/discard.1` instead of `/messages/discard/1` .
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

My View:

```
  <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
              messages_discard_path(@messages.id),
              :method => 'post',
              :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')),
              :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
```

My Routes:

```
  match '/messages/discard' => 'messages#discard', :via => :post
```

Answer (score 1):

Try revising the link_to method and use:

```
messages_discard_path(@messages)
```

Instead.

Also, it looks like that route is missing :id in it. I'm assuming you need match `'/messages/:id/discard' => 'messages#discard', :via => :post` instead.

Comment: Yes, I believe the `.1` is appended because the route does not take any parameters due to the missing `:id`.

Comment: Also, I'd expect it to be `/messages/:id/discard` and not `/message/discard/:id`.

Comment: Thanks. I did that!! But new problem came out! now view's messages_discard_path(@messages) won't work!!it says undefined method `messages_discard_path'

Comment: Run `rake routes | grep discard` and check to see the output. You may have the named route wrong.

Comment: POST   /messages/:id/discard(.:format)   messages#discard     This is output. Now what should I write in my view to execute discard? messages_discard_path(@messages) still takes me to /messages/discard.1

Comment: Yup, you can add `:as => 'desired name'` and then it would be available